# Zoom API participants data if participant rejoined the same meeting

Tags: zoom-sdk

Zoom has an available [JSON data sample](https://developers.zoom.us/docs/api/rest/reference/zoom-api/methods/#operation/pastMeetingParticipants) for fetching a zoom meeting's participants but just wondering how the data would look like if the same participant left the meeting and decides to join the same meeting. (I've been looking for sample but can't find any)

Tried to check it on my own but turns out I need a Pro account in Zoom which I don't have as of now.